# Specify separator for mg-table-pagination AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-material

Consider the image of a table produced from https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjvLVJ?editors=1100

I want to change the way pagination is displayed, as it is typographically incorrect. It should display

> 1–5 of 9

no whitespace between 1 and 5, and `en`-dash as separator.

According to https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table#pagination, the functionality probably should be located in `md-label`, but there's only three properties to the object: `of`, `page` and `rowsPerPage`.

Is there a way to achieve this? https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#pagination doesn't supply a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to modify the [md-data-table.js](https://rawgit.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table/master/dist/md-data-table.js) library with your custom html template.
Download the script and modify below section as

```
<div class="label">{{$pagination.min()}}–{{$pagination.max()}} {{$pagination.label.of}} {{$pagination.total}}</div>
```

Complete html md-table-pagination.html template

```
angular.module('md-table-pagination.html', []).run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('md-table-pagination.html',
    '<div class="page-select" ng-if="$pagination.showPageSelect()">\n' +
    '  <div class="label">{{$pagination.label.page}}</div>\n' +
    '\n' +
    '  <md-select virtual-page-select total="{{$pagination.pages()}}" class="md-table-select" ng-model="$pagination.page" md-container-class="md-pagination-select" ng-change="$pagination.onPaginationChange()" ng-disabled="$pagination.disabled" aria-label="Page">\n' +
    '    <md-content>\n' +
    '      <md-option ng-repeat="page in $pageSelect.pages" ng-value="page">{{page}}</md-option>\n' +
    '    </md-content>\n' +
    '  </md-select>\n' +
    '</div>\n' +
    '\n' +
    '<div class="limit-select" ng-if="$pagination.limitOptions">\n' +
    '  <div class="label">{{$pagination.label.rowsPerPage}}</div>\n' +
    '\n' +
    '  <md-select class="md-table-select" ng-model="$pagination.limit" md-container-class="md-pagination-select" ng-disabled="$pagination.disabled" aria-label="Rows" placeholder="{{ $pagination.limitOptions[0] }}">\n' +
    '    <md-option ng-repeat="option in $pagination.limitOptions" ng-value="option.value ? $pagination.eval(option.value) : option">{{::option.label ? option.label : option}}</md-option>\n' +
    '  </md-select>\n' +
    '</div>\n' +
    '\n' +
    '<div class="buttons">\n' +
    '  <div class="label">{{$pagination.min()}}–{{$pagination.max()}} {{$pagination.label.of}} {{$pagination.total}}</div>\n' +
    '\n' +
    '  <md-button class="md-icon-button" type="button" ng-if="$pagination.showBoundaryLinks()" ng-click="$pagination.first()" ng-disabled="$pagination.disabled || !$pagination.hasPrevious()" aria-label="First">\n' +
    '    <md-icon md-svg-icon="navigate-first.svg"></md-icon>\n' +
    '  </md-button>\n' +
    '\n' +
    '  <md-button class="md-icon-button" type="button" ng-click="$pagination.previous()" ng-disabled="$pagination.disabled || !$pagination.hasPrevious()" aria-label="Previous">\n' +
    '    <md-icon md-svg-icon="navigate-before.svg"></md-icon>\n' +
    '  </md-button>\n' +
    '\n' +
    '  <md-button class="md-icon-button" type="button" ng-click="$pagination.next()" ng-disabled="$pagination.disabled || !$pagination.hasNext()" aria-label="Next">\n' +
    '    <md-icon md-svg-icon="navigate-next.svg"></md-icon>\n' +
    '  </md-button>\n' +
    '\n' +
    '  <md-button class="md-icon-button" type="button" ng-if="$pagination.showBoundaryLinks()" ng-click="$pagination.last()" ng-disabled="$pagination.disabled || !$pagination.hasNext()" aria-label="Last">\n' +
    '    <md-icon md-svg-icon="navigate-last.svg"></md-icon>\n' +
    '  </md-button>\n' +
    '</div>');
}]);
```